# beginner at vaadin- getting error when I try to create a vaadin app

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin

I am trying to create a UI for a java web app using Vaadin.

I am using Eclipse for this purpose, and I have installed the Google Plugin for Eclipse (which includes GWT SDK) as well as the Vaadin plugin for eclipse.

I created a new project using New Project-> New Vaadin Project... but I am seeing an error message in Eclipse console "GWT SDK not installed."

How do I resolve this error? I have already installed Google Plugin for Eclipse which includes GWT SDK.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in 'Preferences->Google->Web Toolkit' if you have existing SDK marked as default. Sometimes, after installing or unistalling other plug-ins, this may get reset to some older, not anymore existing, SDK version.

Also, make sure you have the default (or any other existing SDK) selected in project properties under 'your project->properties->Google->Web Toolkit->GWT SDK'.

Answer (score 2):

Today I resolved this issue (which cropped up after a GWT SDK update on a perfectly working setup) by going to project Properties/Builders and moving the GWT "Google Web Toolkit Project Validator" up to just below Java Builder. I'd tried everything I could think of before that, including uninstalling and re-downloading the SDK, checking default and specific SDK's, trying older ones, editing .classpath entry manually.

Just in case poor some soul follows the path I went through. Using Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: This method worked for me when I converted a GWT app to being a Vaadin app ( Vaadin includes GWT inside it's jar files, so SDK is there ).

Answer (score 1):

help->check for updates
Update all libraries

then:
right-click the project, choose Project Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries

remove invalid GWT library, if any

choose Add Library, choose Google Web Toolkit

If an unknown version of the sdk is selected, click the Configure SDKs link and remove old versions or at least select the current, valid version.

Then, do a Project->clean just to be on the safe side, and your project should now build.

This worked for me using Eclipse Helios.